# Why I don't get more xp in outland?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Playing WoW I went to outland at level 58 , as some guides recommend. Similarly [wiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Formulas:Mob_XP) says that I should get like 190 more XP there than in Azeroth. But all this doesn't work for me somehow.

For example I killed 59 quest mob and get 352 XP.
Meanwhile according to those formulas, and taking into account bonus 10% XP, which I see at the top right, I must get:

```
 (58*5+235)*(1+0.05*(59-58))*110% = 606.375 XP.
```

So why I didn't get all those XP?

P.S. I have counted that 352 XP is exactly what I get if 1. I would be in Azeroth, 2. I would not have those 10% XP bonus.

Comment: XP in WoW is changed every few months, usually to make leveling easier. Most guides are out of date, and the wiki is even worse.

Comment: I don't recommend going to Outland until level 60, so that (1) you can fly, and (2) you can skip Hellfire Peninsula entirely.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, What is wrong with Hellfire Peninsula? I was quite ok at outland at lvl58.

Comment: Oh, you don't have to skip Hellfire Peninsula. But after you level enough alts it gets old and mixing things up is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Wrath of the Lich King (and later Cataclysm), they revamped the XP tables to make grinding in the "old worlds" a bit faster, but later on they leveled it all out so getting to whatever the current area is (MoP, then later Draenor) takes less time, so the XP gain rate from azeroth to outland wouldn't be a big difference, aside from higher level creatures/quests rewarding more experience.

TL;DR: Outlands XP wasn't reduced, but pre- and post-outlands XP was increased as well, so it's more linear now.